# countDocuments() is not working in api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I am trying to get a count of products using api calls but in postman its keep loading

```
router.get(`/get/count`,  async (req, res) => {
  const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count)=>count)
  if (!productCount) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send({
    productCount: productCount
  });
});

(node:28030) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Query was already executed: Product.countDocuments({})
```

without async and await also its not working

I try to catch the error and i got this error in postman

```
{
   "success": false,
   "error": "Query was already executed: Product.countDocuments({})"
}
```

code to catch error:

```
router.get(`/get/count`,   (req, res) => {
   Product.countDocuments((count)=>count).then((pcount)=>{
   if(pcount){
     return res.status(200).json({success:true})
   }else{
      return res.status(404).json({success:false})
   }
   }).catch((err)=>{
     return res.status(400).json({success:false, error:err.message})
   })

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* in Mongoose operations you want to **either** `await` **or** provide a callback, but not both.  Attempting to do both causes it to internally execute the query twice.

Try just:

```
const productCount = await Product.countDocuments();
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to use this in a api call , its still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all the products in your product collection, try this

```
db.product.countDocuments({})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.get(`/get/count`,  async(req, res) => {
  let productCount = await Product.countDocuments();

  if(!productCount){
    res.send(500).json({success:false})
  }

  res.send({productCount: productCount})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two way you can do that**

> **Try it you don't need use callback (count)=>count**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const {Product} = require('../models/products')
const {Category} = require('../models/category')
const catchAsyncErrors = require('../middleware/catchAsyncError')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Get all product 
router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
    let productList = await Product.find().populate('category')

    if(!productList) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false
        })
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        count: productList.length,
        productList

    });
})

router.get(`/count`, catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res) => {
    const countProductList = await Product.countDocuments();

    if(!countProductList){

        res.status(500).json({
            success: false
        })
    }
    res.send({
        success: true,
        countProduct: countProductList
    })

}))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `((count)=>count)`.
Use `Product.countDocuments()` instead